# Create a folder in Documents C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I figured how to create a directory in `c# wpf`. But i do not know how to do it to the current drive folder. Where current drive is the drive windows installed. I used:

**Code UPDATED**

```
String cur = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
cur = cur.Substring(0, 2);
string path1 = @""+cur+"\temp";
if(!Directory.Exists(path1))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path1);
```

But it is giving error saying invalid characters in path. How can i create a folder to another drive?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `path1` exactly when you debug your code?

Comment: @SonerGönül value is `"D:\\\temp"`

Comment: Don't you think you have extra \ ? Your path shouldn't be just D:\\temp ?

Comment: @SonerGönül i corrected...Please check update

Comment: your string "\temp" should either have the slash escaped "\\temp" or as a string literal @"\temp". As-as the \t is a tab character. Some of the answers below suggested good ways to get the right paths/drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the methods available in `System.IO.Path`. They handle the directory separator for you.

Use `Path.GetPathRoot` to get the root drive (i.e. `c:\\`)

```
var root = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

Use `Path.Combine` to combine two paths into a single directory path:

```
var temp = Path.Combine(root, "temp");
```

If all you need is a place to store temporary files, you could consider using:

```
Path.GetTempPath()
```

Comment: It's giving an error: `Path is an ambiguous reference between System.IO.Path and System.Windows.Shapes.Path`

Comment: @user3262659 Then use full name `System.IO.Path` not just `Path`

Comment: The root problem was likely the unescaped \ in your "temp" string, however this is a much better practice and avoids making the mistake in the future. +1